# Javascript file (nocache.js) not uploaded to appengine for gwt project

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, google-plugin-eclipse

I created a GWT project which I wanted to upload to Appengine. It compiles and uploads without an error http://chicbustracker.appspot.com/.
The problem is that the nocache.js file is missing. The project runs fine in development mode and I tried to set up a new project with the same src files, but I get the same error. I also noticed that the favicon.ico is missing as well. I now this is probably way to few information but I do not even now where to look.

Comment: How do you compile it? How to you deploy it? (I suppose using the Google Plugin for Eclipse, but it could just as well be with Maven or an Ant script)

Comment: You are correct. I use compile and deploy with the google plugin and not with maven or ant script. I also had another smaller application that I created similary that I could upload without a problem. stokxxx@appspot.com

Comment: I added the [tag:google-plugin-eclipse] tag as it's where they do support. https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-plugin-eclipse/K2p9Hz3OF88/discussion

Comment: I tried to uploaded the project with the console, with the exact same result: no errors, no Javascript WHY?

Comment: Excuse my silly question but: is the app GWT-compiled? in the same folder you're uploading to AppEngine? [`appcfg`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp) looks so easy to use I doubt it does anything magic/specific about GWT files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the Problem. The folder where my javascript file was in was all samll leters and it seems like the upload was case sensitive. I changed the name of the jscript file and the folder containing it, and now it works. Pretty strange though.